# How to add a function as a method to a returned array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, methods

I have a function intended to be used with the `new` constructor. It should return an array with a value of `["Hello World"]` and include functions as methods. Here is a sample/demo (sorry if it's a little ugly):

```
var my_object = function () {
  this.foo = function (data) { // alert and add new item
    alert(data);
    this.push(data);
  };

  this.bar = function () { // alert and remove last item
    alert(this.pop());
  };

  this.baz = function (stuff) { // replace last item by running previous methods
    this.bar();
    this.foo(stuff);
  };

  var a = "Hello World";
  return [a];
};

var arr = new my_object(); // ["Hello World"]
```

As expected, arr has a value of `["Hello World"]`. However, the following code produces an error:

```
arr.foo('some-text'); // "TypeError: arr.foo is not a function"
```

The same type of error appears with the other two functions. What can I do to make this work, without altering Array.prototype, creating the methods outside the function, or removing the ablity to initialize with `new my_object()`?

Note: If possible, please do not include answers using jQuery or other external libraries.

Comment: `this` is not the value you return from the function, so any of the methods you've declared are thrown away and not used.

Comment: Because your returning an array,.. arrays don't have methods called 'foo'

Comment: so you want to inherit from array and add new methods?

Comment: What is the design idea behind this? `Arrays` are **types**. You are using a function with an object oriented approach but returing an array out of it.

Comment: @RoyiNamir this is not a duplicate of that question. The linked questions answer about **how** the function's default return statement works. This question is **not** about that, to me.

Comment: @briosheje the answer there answers the question. if you return an object from a constructor function , when you new it , it will return that value. not the intended object

Comment: @RoyiNamir I don't think the OP was asking that, the question was: _What can I do to make this work, without altering Array.prototype, creating the methods outside the function, or removing the ablity to initialize with new my_object()?`_ Despite I do agree that the linked question is somehow related to this one, I don't think this is a duplicate. Anyway, it might just be me being too tolerant or not understanding the question :)

Comment: This might help the OP -> https://github.com/wesbos/es6-articles/blob/master/54%20-%20Extending%20Arrays%20with%20Classes%20for%20Custom%20Collections.md

Comment: @Keith I think this might not only help the OP, but it's rather the answer :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, this link has some valuable information -> https://github.com/wesbos/es6-articles/blob/master/54%20-%20Extending%20Arrays%20with%20Classes%20for%20Custom%20Collections.md

Using this, your code could be modified like so,. ->

Of course this is `ES6`, extending arrays was not possible in `ES5` days..

In Chrome `instanceof` when mapped works as expected, but not sure transpiled code would work here, if this was a requirement.  For example if you click the use Babel preset on this snippet you will see it fail, so if you want this to work on old browsers even if trans-piled it may be an issue.

```js
class my_object extends Array {
  foo(data) {
    alert(data);
    this.push(data);
  }

  bar() {
    alert(this.pop());
  }

  baz(stuff) {
    this.bar();
    this.foo(stuff);
  }

  constructor () {
    super("Hello World");
  }
};

var arr = new my_object(); // ["Hello World"]
arr.foo("some-text");

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: This may work even better than the previous answer (ie. less modification on my code). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use any [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) or something what can transpile your code secure is to use [inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain). JavaScript defaults is not object oriented programming but it pretends OOP.

In your case on construct you return `["Hello World"]` which is **array**, **not an instance** of *my_object*. You can return *this* instead of *[a]*.

Besides, you do not have any array you can reference. You work at a local object when you use *this* and you have a probably `TypeError: this.push is not a function`.

I improved your case. See what is return, where I use *this* and reference to *data* array.

Greetings, plum!

Improved code:

```
var my_object = function () {
  this.data = [];
  this.foo = function (data) { // alert and add new item
    alert(data);
    this.data.push(data);
  };

  this.bar = function () { // alert and remove last item
    alert(this.data.pop());
  };

  this.baz = function (stuff) { // replace last item by running previous methods
    this.bar();
    this.foo(stuff);
  };

  var a = "Hello World";
  return this;
};

var arr = new my_object(); // [object Object] - a my_object instance
console.log(arr)
arr.foo('some-text');
```

Comment: Your solution should be posted here instead of an external site. Also, it does not work - it returns *an object* not an array.

Comment: Thanks! It will take a bit of editing on my end to work with the rest of my code, but it will work great.

Comment: @VLAZ I edited my answer, I will keep this in mind on future. You can't return array and work on instance methods. Or you are returning array or an object, but what is the point to returns array from constructor?

Comment: @plumthedev you *could* return an array. More precisely a subclass of an array. Or you could also just do `return []` but then the constructor function is an odd choice. At any rate, I was going off by what OP expressed in the question where the desire was for `arr` to literally be an array. OP never answered comments to specify if this needed to be a literal array, a subclass of array, an array-like, or...apparently, not an array at all, as that's the solution chosen.